# R Shiny imgviewer2

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinyjs

I am trying to embed imgviewer2 (https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer) in my shiny app to be able to zoom and pan the images that I want to display. It works fine but the code interferes with the DT tables of my app. They are not displayed anymore or do not react to my inputs.

I made a small example below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidPage(
          tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href ="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css"),
          tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css", media="screen"),
          tags$head(tags$script(src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js", type="text/javascript")),
          tags$head(tags$meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes")),
          tags$head(tags$script(src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js", type="text/javascript")),
          tags$head(tags$script(src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js", type="text/javascript")),
          tags$head(tags$script(src="imgViewer2.min.js", type="text/javascript")),
          tags$head(tags$script(type="text/javascript", ';(function($) {
            $(window).on("load", function() {
              var $img = $("#image1").imgViewer2();
            });
          })(jQuery);')),
          tags$div(img(src="https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png", width="80%", id="image1")),
          selectizeInput("sample2", "Sample: ",
                         choices = c("cyl", "mpg", "disp", "hp")),
          DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )))


server <- function(input, output) {

mtcars2 <- reactive({

    mtcars2 <- mtcars

    return(mtcars2)
}) 

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    mtcars2 <- mtcars2()
    mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars2, select = c(input$sample2))

    table <- DT::datatable(mtcars2, rownames = FALSE)

})   

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I isolate the imgviewer code such that it does not interfere with the DT in my application? I tried to wrap the function into singleton() based on this question [zoomable image map in RStudio Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041253/zoomable-image-map-in-rstudio-shiny/26044171#26044171) but that did not help.

Comment: I have tried and it works (with `"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/imgviewer2@1.1.0/dist/imgViewer2.min.js"`). But I have not included jquery because it is already included by Shiny.